# How to segue UIImage?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiimage, segue

I am using Swift to segue my image across from my `NewsTableViewController.swift` to my `NewsDetailTableViewController.swift`. How do I go about doing this?

Here is my `prepareForSegue()` method in my `NewsTableViewController.swift`:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?){

    if segue.identifier == "showDetail" {

        if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            let destinationController = segue.destinationViewController as! NewsDetailTableViewController
            destinationController.item = items[indexPath.row]
        }
    }
}
```

The `item` reference refers to the labels in the `NewsDetailTableViewController.swift`. They are brought to the UI by JSON. My image is not a part of JSON, they are in my Xcode image assets file.

I am using Swift as my language.

Here is an image of my simulator: [image: Click here]

Answer (score 0):

Make a property in `NewsDetailTableViewController`:

```
class NewsDetailTableViewController {
    ...
    var image: UIImage!
    ...
}
```

and assign it in `prepareForSegue`:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?){

    if segue.identifier == "showDetail" {

        if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            let destinationController = segue.destinationViewController as! NewsDetailTableViewController
            destinationController.item = items[indexPath.row]
            let yourImage = UIImage(named: "yourImageInAssetsName")
            destinationController.image = yourImage
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is not showing up in my simulator. I'll add an image to my question.

Comment: Perhaps you forget to assign `UIImage` to `UIImageView` in `NewsDetailTableViewController`?

Comment: It's still not showing up. Would it matter that in the main VC, the image size is 0x0, but in the detail VC, it is 400x216

Comment: Show code for `NewsDetailTableViewController` where you assign UIImage from seque to UIImageView.

Comment: All I added in the `NewsDetailTableViewController` was `var image:UIImageView!`